Rational normal curves and their defyning matrices
I have some doubts on rational normal curves. It is well-known, for instance by Harris (Algebraic Geometry, a first course) that a curve $C\subseteq\mathbb{P}^d$ is a rational normal curve of degree $d$ if and only if it is defined by the $2\times 2$ minors of a matrix of the form
$$\Omega=\begin{pmatrix} F_1 & F_2 & \dots & F_d \\
 G_1 & G_2 & \dots & G_2\end{pmatrix}$$
such that any matrix conjugate to $\Omega$ has no zero entry. My first question is: when two different matrices define the same rational normal curve? I have looked for the answer on Harris's book, but I could not find it.
About my second question: I know that the family of rational normal curves of degree $d$ has dimension $(d-1)(d+3)$. In the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0603137 it is written that the family of rational curves of degree $d$ passing through a point has dimension $(d-1)(d+2)$ and this can be proved by an easy argument on the definying matrix of the rational normal curve, but I could not find a way to prove that in a formal way.
Could someone please help me with these two question or indicate a reference for them? I would be very thankful.


The matrix is defined by the curve up to the natural $\mathrm{GL}_2 \times \mathrm{GL}_d$ action.

You can think of this matrix as a linear map
$$
\mathbb{P}^d \to \mathbb{P}(\Bbbk^2 \otimes \Bbbk^{d}).
$$
Then the condition you are looking for is that the image of a given point lies on the Segre subvariety
$$
\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^{d-1} \subset \mathbb{P}(\Bbbk^2 \otimes \Bbbk^{d}).
$$
Since its codimension is $d-1$, the imposed condition also has codimension $d-1$.



Dear Sasha, thank you very much for your elegant and clear answer !

Here are some more simple-minded alternatives to Sasha's elegant answer to Question 2. They might be useful in thinking about other questions of this kind.

Since $\mathbf P^d$ is homogeneous, you might as well assume the point is $(1 \colon 0 \colon \cdots \colon 0)$. Evaluating your matrix $\Omega$ at this point, you get the $2 \times d$ matrix whose entries are the coefficients of $x_0$ in the forms $F_i$ and $G_i$. The condition that this point lies on the curve is that this matrix should have rank at most 1, which evidently imposes $d-1$ independent conditions on these coefficients.

Let $U_d$ denote the space of all rational normal curves in $\mathbf P^d$. I use the fact that $U_d$ is irreducible. Consider the "incidence correspondence"
$$ I = \left\{ (p, C) \in \mathbf P^d \times U_d \mid p \in C \right\}$$
This comes with projection maps $\pi_1 \colon I \rightarrow \mathbf P^d$ and $\pi_2 \colon I \rightarrow U_d$. Your question is asking for the dimension of the fibre of $\pi_1$ over any point of $\mathbf P^d$. Now the fibre of $\pi_2$ over a point $C \in U_d$ is easy to understand: it is just $C$ itself. In particular $I$ is irreducible and has codimension $d-1$ in $\mathbf P^d \times U_d$. This implies that the fibres of $\pi_1$ all have codimension $d-1$ in $U_d$ also.



Dear Lazzaro, I really thank you for giving me this more “practical” answer. It is very useful for me!
